# Making a "piece of paper with text on it" in OpenGL (Specifically on iOS 5)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I've never done OpenGL, but I'm looking for some pointers on this particular question on an AR app I'm practicing with.

I'd like to make an app with a "flat rectangle" along with text written on the surface of the rectangle.  Visually, I'm imagining something along the lines of a piece of paper with text written on it.  Each time the app starts, the text would be something different (the text is pulled from a plist file).

The user would be able to view the paper from all sides, much as if there was a piece of paper hanging in front of him.

Is this trivial to do in OpenGL?  How could I get started?

Sorry for the really open-ended question, but I wanted to get a feel for how this kind of thing is done.

Looking at the OpenGL template source code in the Xcode sample projects, I see that there is a big array of vertices.  I presume that to create a "flat" rectangle, I'd essentally just have to remove or make the z-axis zero.  And then the dynamic text that will attach to the surface of the flat rectangle...I dont have any idea how to do that......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is hard to answer unambiguously. In general, this is trivial, but then again it is not.

Drawing a "flat rectangle with something on it" is a couple of API calls, as simple as it can get. Drawing text in OpenGL *in an efficient way, and high quality, and without big preprocessing* is an entirely different story.

What I would do is render text using whatever the "normal system-supported" way is under iOS (just like you would draw in any window, I wouldn't know this specific detail), but draw *into a bitmap* rather than on the screen. This should be supported, pretty much every OS has supported this for at least 10-15 years. Then turn this bitmap into a texture, bind it, and draw your trivial flat quad with OpenGL (set up a vertex buffer with 4 vertices, each vertex a texture coordinate, and draw two triangles - as easy as it gets).

The huge advantage of that is that you get to use the installed system fonts (or any fonts available), you don't need to generate a bitmap font and don't need to think about really ugly things such as hinting and proper spacing, and it's much easier to mix different text styles, etc. OpenGL has built-in support for text too, of course, but it is not terribly efficient or nice either. If the text does not change every millisecond, it's really best to render it using the standard renderer that the operating system provides (yes, that probably won't be hardware accelerated, but so what... since the user must read the text, it likely won't change every millisecond).

Now it gets more complicated if your "piece of paper" should bend and twist too, or do a page peel effect rather than being just a flat rectangle. In that case you need to tesselate it, which can be harder than it sounds, too. Not all tesselations look optimal for all bends/twists, or they do but do not have the optimal (read as minimum) number of vertices.

There is an article on "page peel" and such tesselation in one of the GPU Gems or GPU Pro books, let me search...

There: *Andreas Bizzotto: "A Shader-Based eBook Reader - Page peeling effect", GPU Pro2 pp. 278-299*

Maybe you can get hold of a copy or are lucky enough to find it on Google Books or something.